# `make` in Windows stopped working because of "write error"

Tags: windows, gnu-make

I have had `make` for Windows ([gnuwin32.sourceforge.net](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)) installed on my W11 machine and today it just stopped working out of a sudden, without even a computer restart taking place between the last time I was able to run it successfully and now.

This is what I'm seeing now when trying to run it, directly from the binary location:

```bash
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin> make.exe
make: *** ??????????????????·??????, makefile ?????????????.  ???.

C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin> make.exe -version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
???·??????????????????????. ??????????????????????·???????????.
????????????????????????????????????·??, ??????????.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
make: write error
```

I already tried the restart + uninstall + reinstall + restart path with no luck.

I find it weird that half of the license text is corrupted.

Any clue what could be causing it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I installed [v4.4.1 from Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/make).